# How to write server name in connection string at web.config file

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, connection-string

I need to know that how to write server name in connection string at webconfig where as Database is mysql and and it is on localhost:8080 and using asp.net web.config file for writing connection string

```
<add key="mySqlConn" value="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost:8080;     PORT=3306;DATABASE=dbname; UID=root; PASSWORD=; OPTION=3"/>
```

I had put this snippet in web.config file but got this error

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The things i need to know plz check

1. Servername as locally it runs on localhost:8080 due to skype.
2. Driver name.(What connector we have to install either phpmyadmin one or previous one as my phpmyadmin is upgraded)

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: @nickles80 my server name is correct?

Answer (score -1):

You're not specifying the port properly for localhost. Is your port 8080 or 3306? Set your `value` parameter to this:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Port=YOURPORTNUMBER;
Database=dbname;User=root;Password=;Option=3
```

Comment: i have checked both port number 8080 and 3306 but they are not working for me

Comment: i am running phpmyadmin like this localhost:8080\phpmyadmin so how can i write my server name and driver